# js if or not working

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this for over an hour now and don't know whats wrong with it...
code is below

```
var webkit = (browsername == (("Safari")||("Chrome")))? true : false;
```

It should return a true value for chrome and safari but not Internet Explore, Opera or Firefox
I don't get why it returns true with safari but not chrome? any suggestions?

Even when I change it up a bit it still does this

```
if (browsername == (("Safari")||("Chrome")))
        webkit = true;
```

Am I doing my **or** wrong?

Comment: `"safari||"Chrome" ==> "Safari"`, since `"Safari"` is truthy

Comment: try this http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm

Comment: Actually, why do you need to browser-detect?

Comment: PS. It's recommended to use the `===` operator, at least when you don't know the difference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: Its just for something that I am working on, I don't really need it, but may need it in the future :D

Comment: @ryanc1256 except for extreme cases, if you need to know what the browser is you're doing it wrong because tests based on specific browser versions are brittle.  For this reason jQuery has deprecated the `$.browser` feature.  Look at using something like `Modernizr` to test for _feature_ compatibility, not _browser_ versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do. It should be

```
var webkit = (browsername == "Safari")||(browsername == "Chrome");
```

Comment: and I will five minutes :D

Comment: @ryanc1256 no, no, no!  `predicate ? true : false` is just the same as writing `predicate` - the ternary operator is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

use this type

```
if (browsername == ("Safari")||browsername == ("Chrome"))
    webkit = true;
```

Comment: This won't set webkit to false if the if doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `||` that way, you should use:

```
var webkit = (browsername == "Safari" || browsername == "Chrome");
```

and

```
if (browsername == "Safari" || browsername == "Chrome") { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you're using **or** and the **==** operators the wrong way. == in JavaScript can only compare one value with one different value at once and therefore works different than its use in spoken language. Try:

```
var webkit = (browsername == "Safari" || browsername == "Chrome") ? true : false;
```

EDIT: Thanks to Alnitak for the hint about the redundant ternary operator:

```
var webkit = browsername == "Safari" || browsername == "Chrome";
```

Comment: Actually I see now you were just copying the OP but I can't revert the downvote until the answer is edited.

Comment: downvote reverted.  But please put braces around the entire expression, and use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this in jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var browser=$.browser.webkit;
    });
```

It will return true for chrome and safari and "undefined " for other browsers